# Как исправить данный код,чтобы в edit control'е выводился полученный ответ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

данные вводятся из эдит контролов по нажатию button'ов , если нажимать на первый, то программа просто зависает, если нажать на 2, то в программе ничего не происходит,Она должна вывести полученный ответ сначала в 1 edit под ответ потом во 2 edit под ответ,но этого не происходит,приветствуются любые предложения.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DialogA.h"
#include<string>
#include <sstream> 
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Глобальные переменные:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна

int nomer = 0,a1,b1,a2,b2,eps,n1,n2;

struct point{
    int x, y;
};
int n;
point mass[100]{ 0 };
HWND okno;
// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    DlgProc2(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: разместите код здесь.

    // Инициализация глобальных строк
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_DIALOGA, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Выполнить инициализацию приложения:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_DIALOGA));

    MSG msg;

    // Цикл основного сообщения:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: регистрирует класс окна.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_DIALOGA));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_DIALOGA);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   ФУНКЦИЯ: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ: сохраняет обработку экземпляра и создает главное окно.
//
//   КОММЕНТАРИИ:
//
//        В данной функции дескриптор экземпляра сохраняется в глобальной переменной, а также
//        создается и выводится на экран главное окно программы.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить дескриптор экземпляра в глобальной переменной

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  ФУНКЦИЯ: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ:  обрабатывает сообщения в главном окне.
//
//  WM_COMMAND — обработать меню приложения
//  WM_PAINT — отрисовать главное окно
//  WM_DESTROY — отправить сообщение о выходе и вернуться
//
//

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Разобрать выбор в меню:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case IDM_vvod:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, DlgProc);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            okno = hWnd;
            HPEN pen;
            pen = CreatePen(0, 1, RGB(100,100,100));
            SelectObject(hdc, pen);
            for( int i=0;i<nomer-1;i++ ){
                MoveToEx(hdc,mass[i].x,mass[i].y,NULL);
                LineTo(hdc,mass[i+1].x,mass[i+1].y);
            }
            // TODO: Добавьте сюда любой код прорисовки, использующий HDC...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Обработчик сообщений для окна "О программе".
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

double Fintegral(double x)
{
    return 2 * x + 3;
}
double Fyravn(double x) {
    return x + 1;
}
INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON2) {
            a1 = GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_EDITA1, NULL, true);
            b1= GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_EDITB1, NULL, true);
            eps= GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDITEPS, NULL, true);
            n1= GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_EDITN1, NULL, true); 
            double shag = (b1 - a1) / n1;
            double fx0 = Fintegral(a1);
            double fxn = Fintegral(b1);
            double sumnech = 0.0;
            double sumch;
            for (sumch = a1 + shag; sumch < b1 - shag; sumch += 2.0 * shag) {
                sumnech += Fintegral(sumch);
            }

            sumnech *= 4.0;
            sumch = 0.0;

            double I;
            for (I = a1 + 2.0 * shag; I < b1 - shag; I += 2.0 * shag) {
                sumch += Fintegral(I);
            }

            sumch *= 2.0;
            I = shag * (fx0 + fxn + sumnech + sumch) / 3.0;
            std::wstringstream ss;
            ss <<I;
            SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDITOTVET, ss.str().c_str());
        }
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON1) {
            a2 = GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_A2, NULL, true);
            b2 = GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_B2, NULL, true);
            double tochnost = GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_tochn, NULL, true);
            
            //ArrayList<Double> znach = new ArrayList();
            double Atek = a2;

            for(double Btek = a2 + 0.6; Btek <= b2; Atek += 0.6) {
            double f_Atek = Fyravn(Atek);
            Btek = Atek + 0.6;
            double f_Btek = Fyravn(Btek);
            if (f_Atek * f_Btek < 0.0) {
            double tempA = Atek;
            double tempB = Btek;
            while(tempB - tempA > 0.001) {
            double Xm = (tempA + tempB) / 2.0;
            double f_Xm = Fyravn(Xm);
            if (f_Atek * f_Xm <= 0.0) {
            tempB = Xm;
            } else {
            tempA = Xm;
            f_Atek = f_Xm;
            }
            }

            double temp = (tempA + tempB) / 2.0;
            std::wstringstream ss2;
            ss2 << temp;
            SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDITOTV2, ss2.str().c_str());
            //InvalidateRect(hInst, false, false);
            }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все ссылки проверил и привязки везде правильные.
[весь проект для скачивания](https://yadi.sk/d/Bl9hoLokCYB7MQ)

Comment: Отладчиком проходили?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а можно вместе с программой получить полный код проекта? Чтобы тоже запустить его под отладчиком. Там же кроме самого текста программы еще файлы ресурсов, *.vcprj и *.sln - файлы. Без них запустить у себя и посмотреть, как оно работает - тяжело.

Comment: добрый день, не знаю что именно было нужно добавил ссылку на яндекс диск для скачивания проекта целиком.

Comment: @РоманВороновский чтобы человек увидел оповещение о вашем сообщении, пишите собаку + его ник в сообщении

Comment: @S.H. в самом конце после кода программы находится ссылка

Comment: @РоманВороновский Файл `DialogA.cpp`, строка `231` может быть деление на ноль! Если ввести единицы зависания нет, скорей всего проблемы с ошибками в реализации алгоритма.